# Countng number of rows of table and getting every cell value

Tags: javascript, jquery

My question is that I have found the code to traverse every row and cell but I am not able to understand how do i fetch every cell value with this code ? Can anyone help me with this code. I want to use this code only in my project.

Here is my js code

```
    var table = document.getElementById('tblOne');
    var rowCount = $('.table tr').length - 1;
    for(var i=0; i<rowCount; i+=1){
      var row = table.rows[i];
      //your code goes here, looping over every row.
      //cells are accessed as easy

      var cellLength = row.cells.length;
      for(var y=0; y<cellLength; y+=1){
        var cell = row.cells[y];
        console.log(cell);
        //do something with every cell here
      }
    }
```

Comment: What problem are you having exactly? where it says `var cell = row.cells[y]` is where you have access to each cell.

Answer (score 0):

Following will help

```
var cell = row.cells[y];
console.log($(cell).text());
```

Comment: My another question how do i get a specific column value with this code which have a specific class say salary ?

Comment: you need to get salary column index, lets say its 3
then 
`if(y===3){
 console.log("Salary",$(cell).text());
}`